# Summarize/Parallelize a (recursively) rename task in powershell

Tags: powershell, replace, rename

I have to rename a big bunch of files and replace text in filenames like a1 to a2 and b1 to b2 etc...
Because it's a very large amount of files I want to summarize/parallelize/replace several texts at once to not  let powershell recursively do the task (with different text) over and over again/in a row but simultaneously...

the org (in a row one, which is too slow) I use is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.replace("__a1","__a2") }

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.replace("__b1","__b2") }

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.replace("__c1","__c2") }
```

And I am looking for a solution which works like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.replace("__a1","__a2" | "__b1","__b2" | "__c1","__c2") }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly the next time? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually chain multiple replace operations in Powershell. It should work like this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File) | 
  Rename-Item -NewName {
    $_.Name  -replace '__a1','__a2' -replace '__b1','__b2'  -replace '__c1','__c2'
  } -WhatIf
```

If you're satisfied with the result remove the `-WhatIf`.

Comment: thank you but it doesnt change the file name (even if whatif is removed)

Comment: Remove the `-Include` parameter. I corrected the code suggestion.

Comment: so sorry but somehow it still doesnt affect the filenames

Comment: Well it works on my machine. I just tested it.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File) | 
  Rename-Item -NewName {
    $_.Name  -replace '__a1','__a2' -replace '__b1','__b2'  -replace '__c1','__c2'
  } is that right?

Comment: Are you sure the characters in your file names are what you expect? There might be special charecters in it. You could copy an original file name and add it to your question (formatted as code please).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Windows PowerShell, you can make use of the `MatchEvaluator` argument `::Replace()` static method takes for the `[regex]` class:

```
$pattern = '(?<=__\w)(\d)'
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*__*' -File -Recurse | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { 
        [regex]::Replace($_.BaseName,$pattern,{Param($matched) [int]$matched.Groups[1].Value + 1}) 
    } -WhatIf
```

When using a script block as a match evaluator in PowerShell, the `$matches` automatic variable won't be available, and you'll have to use your own variable to populate the results. Here, I used `$matched` as the parameter instead.

The `$matched` object represents a Match object, which has the following properties:

- **Value**: The matched string.
- **Groups**: A collection of groups within the match.
- **Index**: The position in the original string where the first character of the matched substring is found.
- **Length**: The length of the matched string.
- **Success**: Indicates if the match is successful.

Given your use case, where you want to increment the digit, we can match the ending digit with the pattern [`(?<=__\w)(\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/p1fRU4/1). Then, our 1st `[1]` group matched would be the digit `(\d)`, where you access the `Value` property to obtain the digit itself. Finally, increment it by type-casting the value of the matched digit to `[int]`, so we can increase it by 1 using the addition operator `+ 1`.

This results in new names with the digit increased by 1 such as:

```
__a1 -> __a2
__b1 -> __b2
__c1 -> __c2
__d1 -> __d2
...etc
```

making it a dynamic renaming procedure without the manual input of each individual pattern to look for and replace with.